# How to hibernate application?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

my question may seem too weird but i thought about the windows hibernation thing and i was wondering if there is a way to hibernate a specific process or application.
i.e : when windows start up from a normal shutdown/restart it will load all startup programs normally but in addition of that it will load a specific program with it`s previous status before shutting down the computer.

I have though about reserving the memory location and retrieve it back when computer start up , but is there any application that does that in windows environment ?

Comment: That's not likely to work, since shared things referenced in memory would have moved.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is to create a full dump of your process, and then debug it after the restart instead of launching it as a regular program. This will let you store the state of the program, but you'll have to figure out a way to get that debugging session look like a normal launch. If that's possible. In general, though, serialization is probably the right mechanism for such hibernation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That cannot work.  The state of a process is almost never contained in just the process itself.  A gui app creates user32 and gdi objects that are stored in a heap associated with the desktop.  It makes calls to Windows that affect the window manager state.  It makes I/O calls that cause code inside drivers to run.  Which in turn affects allocations inside the kernel pools.  Multiply the trouble by every pipe or rpc channel it opens to talk to other processes.  And shared resources like the clipboard.

Only making a snapshot of the entire operating system state works.

Comment: In Windows 8 there will be something like the OP wants, but only for the inner core components (drivers, kernel). When the system shuts down the will be - in difference to the user applications - only hibernated.

Comment: Thank you so much for these great information , i am now aware of what i really need.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this now, in Linux OS:  CRIU, CryoPID2, BLCR.

I think docker can be used (both for windows & linux), but it requires pre-packaging your app in a docker, which bears some overhead(s).